# Scroll the UICollectionView elements automatically as the view appears like a slideshow.

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im working on a project in swift 3 and currently I can go through the UICollectionView items by dragging one after the other. My requirement is to display them (the items) as a slide-show without dragging them (need to disable this)as the screen appears. My code as of now as bellow. Since I'm new to swift help would be much appreciated.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SuggestedCell", for: indexPath) as! SuggestedMP3CollectionViewCell
        //background of collectionview
        let view=UIView()
        view.backgroundColor=UIColor(patternImage:collectionViewImageArray [indexPath.row])
        cell.backgroundView=view
        cell.featuredSongLabel.text = "Featured Song"
        cell.suggestedHealerNameLabel.text = "Healer"
        cell.suggestedTeaserDescriptionLabel.text = "Teaser"
        cell.suggestedMusicImageView.image = imageArray [indexPath.row]
       // cell.suggestedMusicImageView.image = collectionViewImageArray [indexPath.row]
        return cell


    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return 20

       //return collectionViewCount!
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

            return 1
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you configure your collection view or reload it, you need to add a timer for autoscrolling.

```
let kAutoScrollDuration: CGFloat = 4.0
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: kAutoScrollDuration, target: self, selector: #selector(self.nextPage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Now your timer will call nextPage after specified time interval

```
func nextPage() {
        // 1.back to the middle of sections
    var currentIndexPathReset = self.resetIndexPath()
        // 2.next position
    var nextItem: Int = currentIndexPathReset.item + 1
    if nextItem == self.banners.count {
        nextItem = 0
    }
    var nextIndexPath = IndexPath(item: nextItem, section: 0)
    // 3.scroll to next position
    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: nextIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .left, animated: true)
}
```

Now if we have reached the last index then we need to reset the indexPath, so for that we have resetIndexPath method and also it will return the currentIndexPath.

```
func resetIndexPath() -> IndexPath {
        // currentIndexPath
    var currentIndexPath: IndexPath? = self.collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems?.last
        // back to the middle of sections
    var currentIndexPathReset = IndexPath(item: currentIndexPath?.item, section: 0)
    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: currentIndexPathReset, atScrollPosition: .left, animated: false)
    return currentIndexPathReset!
}
```

Comment: In the "nextPage" function can you explain what is "self.banner.count"

Comment: For me self.banner.count gives the number of cells in collectionView, as self.banner is a array of objects

Comment: Thank u very much